# How whatsApp hides authentication SMS in Android KitKat?

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-4.4-kitkat, android-broadcast, whatsapp, android-5.1.1-lollipop

We know that Android KitKat doesn't support ***abortBroadcast();*** anymore. How WhatsApp blocks the very first incoming authentication SMS? I was wondering because I have a SMS filter app which no more works for KitKat.

Thanks in advance. (Sorry for my bad English.)